# Direction of the magnetic field from a singular coil

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, gauss-law

As I am currently studying for a neurophysics exam I stumble across an issue that I fail to grasp, mainly the direction of the magnetic field, I know that it is possible to apply the right hand rule and find for this question that for position A it must be downwards, I however do not see why there must be X-components, since the magnetic field for a current loop is only in the z-direction, if somebody could explain to me why there is a horizontal component in O and B and how to find this it would be appreciated. I can't apply the image principle here as this is only for electric field.

Thanks for the help in advance[image]

[image: Exercise]

Comment: I would expect that there is only a vertical component as the loop has a current going in a clockwise direction

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the magnetic field lines of a coil, it looks somewhat like this:

[image: magnetic field lines]

At the center, the lines emerge vertically outward and hence you don't have a horizontal component to it. However, the moment you shift away, the field lines are at an angle and when you try to resolve this along perpendicular directions, you get both horizontal and vertical components (shown by red arrows).